# I need to print a graph using matplotlib

Tags: python

I have a task for class which leads: Use matplotlib and print the dots that ends up inside the circle
and outside where x = (-1, 1) and y = (-1, 1). Use different colors.

It has to do with an earlier task i did where i did this:

```
import math
import random
inne = 0


for i in range (15):

    x1 = random.uniform(-1,1)
    y1 = random.uniform(-1,1)

    avstånd = math.sqrt((x1-0)2+(y1-0)2)

    print(avstånd)

    if avstånd <= 1: 
        inne +=1


print(f"det finns {inne}st punkter innanför cirkeln.")
```

Can somone help me print these out in a graph using matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

You can plot points graph using Matplotlib like this:

```
import numpy as np  # not necessary, just to generate example points
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(0,10):  # generate some random points
    x = np.random.rand()
    y = np.random.rand()
    plt.scatter(x, y, color='red')  # Add point into graph, set color to it
plt.show()  # Shows the final result
```

You can simply edit this to your need by adding `if` condition and choose color according to it. I'm not entirely sure what exactly you want, next time I would recommend using English in your code.